# What do the letters WHL and LS stand for in the description and name of Earendel star, and other distant objects?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, space-telescope

Earendel star's official name includes the abbreviations WHL and LS, as do some other very far-off objects....

What do they stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WHL is an initialism of "Wen Han Liu", the names of three astronomers and the authors of a catalog [A Catalog of 132,684 Clusters of Galaxies Identified from Sloan Digital Sky Survey III](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012ApJS..199...34W/abstract)

- Zhonglue Wen (文中略)  (Z.L. Wen)
- Jinlin Han (韩金林) (J.L. Han)
- Liu () (F.S Liu)

[if anyone can find Liu's full details please feel free to edit them in)

I can't find a definitive source for the meaning of "LS", but I speculate that it means "lensed star" or "Lensed source".